# ItemsSource in combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

a simple xaml:

```
<ComboBox
    Height="23" Name="status"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    ItemsSource="?"
    Width="120">
</ComboBox>
```

What you need to write to С# that stick items in the drop-down list right here

Comment: Can't you just google it? It's simple binding.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825480/set-itemssource-of-a-combobox-to-an-array-of-integers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ItemsSource` is a simple binding to a collection of [something] that will fill out the combolist, here's a quick sample:

```
public class MyDataSource
{
    public IEnumerable<string> ComboItems 
    {
        get
        {
            return new string[] { "Test 1", "Test 2" };
        }
    }
}

<ComboBox
    Height="23" Name="status"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ComboItems}"
    Width="120">
</ComboBox>
```

That's not a complete sample, but it gives you the idea.

It's also worth noting that you **don't have to use** the `ItemsSource` property, this is also acceptable:

```
<ComboBox
    Height="23" Name="status"
    IsReadOnly="False"
    Width="120">
    <ComboBox.Items>
        <ComboBoxItem>Test 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Test 2</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```